# Unicode character 0x25BA not displayed on Android

Tags: android, unicode

I'm trying to display the [\u25BA unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25ba/index.htm) in a textview, but doing

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/arrowright" android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp" android:gravity="center" android:text="\u25BA"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:textColor="#000000" />
```

only displays an empty rectangle. This works with other character such as "\u2605".

Is the set of characters android can display limited?

Comment: The set of characters that **any device** can display is limited: If there is no font that has the specified glyph, then it can't be displayed. And **no font** provides full coverage of the **entire** Unicode spec.

Comment: But is is possible to test programmatically if a particular character can be displayed by a given font?

Comment: @Patrick: it is possible, outside Android (or with a rooted Android). You basically open the font file (it is OpenType) and interpret the tables according with the OpenType spec (http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/). For instance this is what this tool does: http://mihai-nita.net/2007/09/08/charmapex-some-kind-of-character-map/. (and, of course, tons of applications that edit fonts directly :-)

Comment: @Joachim: The `Arial Unicode` font that is usually installed with MSOffice contains most of the Unicode characters. It is also rather big, over 20MB.

Comment: @ccpizza: According to Wikipedia the latest version of Arial Unicode has 50,377 glyphs (or 38,917 characters) defined. And Version 6.0 of the Unicode standard defines 109,449 characters. I wouldn't call that "most". While I agree that it probably contains most characters that most people need from day-to-day, my basic point still stands: no font provides *full* coverage (and such a font would have only limited, specialized use).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML does not allow you to use `\u` unicode escapes, use proper encoding, probably UTF-8 or escape it using `&...;` escaping.

Yes, the characters are limited by what the current Font supports. Use a font browser to check if the desired character is supported or not.

Comment: I can set `android:text="\u2605"` and it properly displays the corresponding unicode character. How can I know which font to use, and how can I set it?

Comment: See my answer below. I believe the most practical way is having your smartphone ready with a table of possible values in Android. See the app that I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading [Unicode Map](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.madore.android.unicodeMap) on the Market, and keep it handy when you're developing. It uses the `\uXXXX` notation.

And finally, as sorin said, remember (if you don't already) that the `\uXXXX` (two hex bytes) only seems to work in `strings.xml` (and importing to layouts using the `@string/string_name` format). Or at least it does not seem to work in all SDKs, or in all environments (here, I just tested on SDK 2.2 and it does *not* work). To avoid trouble (chars in middle of literal strings, etc), I don't do that.

Since most people never hard code the strings in XML layouts directly (localization issues etc.), that generally isn't a problem (and that's why I use this format). Also, as you can see in the app above, this seems to be the preferred way of escaping less-than-trivial characters in Android.

Personally, I believe that's why I don't see many people using `&#int;`, I guess...

Hope this helps!

Comment: By the way, I am *not* the author of that app.